# Can't find init.vim

Tags: neovim

I can't seem to find my `init.vim`. I believe it is supposed to be under `~/Neovim/share/nvim` but the only folder there is runtime. Do I have to make a file called `init.vim`? If so, where do I put it?

If anyone is still reading this, I have not fixed the problem. I have found where `init.vim` should be but it is not there and when I try to create the file I cannot write it when I save it. Even when I do it as administrator, I cannot write the file.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

the config file for neovim is at `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`. or if set `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim`. you can get more info with `:help nvim-config` from your neovim instance.

Comment: What is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`. When I did `:help nvim-configuration`, it said that I should use `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim` for my configuration.

Comment: I personally don't use `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable but you can if you want to (if you want to know more about it [freedesktop](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html). neovim will look at `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` if it's not defined. what OS are you running?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: I don't know much about windows, maybe this will help [windows installation](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#user-content-windows)

Comment: I think I opened the right file but I can't write the file.

Comment: what permission are on the file? do you have admin privilege? maybe this will help [windows permission](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure but whenever I open it, it says new directory so not sure if the file actually exists.

Comment: `$XDG_CONFIG` is not set when the default value `~/.config` should be used https://superuser.com/a/425712/114341

Answer (score 19):

I couldn't find `init.vim` at `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` in Ubuntu 18.04. I installed neovim with neovim [instructions](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#ubuntu):

> Since 18.04 As in Debian, neovim is in Ubuntu.
>
> `sudo apt install neovim`
>
> Python (:python) support seems to be automatically installed
>
> ```
> sudo apt install python-neovim
> sudo apt install python3-neovim
> ```

So instead, I use [vim-bootstrap](http://vim-bootstrap.com/)  to create the config file and put in neovim configuration:

```
mkdir ~/.config/nvim & cp ~/Downloads/generate.vim ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

PD: I am using `zsh` shell and I have `vim` installed.

Comment: thanks, vim-bootstrap even has RUST setup plugin with neovim

Comment: Also, a nice alternative to bootstrap vim/neovim configuration is [SpaceVim](https://spacevim.org/quick-start-guide/#install) a distribution for vim/neovim

Answer (score 18):

For Windows 10, the neovim's init.vim file is located in `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim`.  Typically, it would be located in : `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim`.  Change `USERNAME` with your username.

Comment: With :help init.vim you can get the location for init.vim. For windows it is ~/AppData/Local/nvim/init.vim Or $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim.

Comment: 1. You can have literally an empty init.vim file in %AppData% and config will be taken from a different place.
2. :help init.vim sometimes doesn't work. On my machine it yields an error `E149: Sorry, no help for init.vim`

Comment: This was very useful , thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15):

On ubuntu, I created on my own a directory /.config/nvim and init.vim configuration file and that worked.

```
mkdir ~/.config/nvim
nvim ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

Answer (score 5):

from within neovim do

`:echo $MYVIMRC`

to display the full path to the currently used init.vim file

Answer (score 0):

To find and edit your init.vim, do the following in sequence (assuming you use a Unix-based terminal):

```
~ cd /root/.config/nvim
~ nvim init.vim
```

This worked for me using Windows and running on the Ubuntu terminal, should work for other distributions too.

Answer (score -4):

For Windows, init.vim was located in `Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\plugin`

Comment: I could not find it at this location.